# Anaconda ya no responde

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Intento descargar una libreria pero cada vez que lo hecho parace que anaconda no responde:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\Python>conda create --name env_cvxopt python=3.7
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\Python>
```

Y que ya sea que esté en la terminal de pycharm o de anaconda...

Puedo activar un entorno pero no installar librerias:

```
(base) C:\Users\antoi>conda activate mod_env

(mod_env) C:\Users\antoi>conda install -c conda-forge cvxopt
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

Informaciones utiles:

```
(mod_env) C:\Users\antoi>

(mod_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\Python>echo %CONDA_PREFIX%
C:\Users\antoi\.conda\envs\mod_env

(mod_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\Python>where python
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

## Actualizacion

Intenté anadirlo en el PATH pero no funciona:

```
(mod_env) C:\Users\antoi>export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Entonces verifiqué la version de Anaconda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal vez hay un problema con las versiones?

Comment: No me queda claro el error, aparentemente puedes crear y activar un entorno, también instalar un paquete (resultados **`done`**). Veo que intentas instalar el paquete `cvxopt` sobre el entorno `mod_env` en lugar del que acabas de crear `env_cvxopt`. En la ultima imagen, también se ve que teniendo activo el entorno `mod_env` intentas crear el entorno `env_cvxopt`. Intenta `conda deactivate` para quedar en `(base) C:\users\user_name>` y luego `conda activate env_cvxopt`. Con el entorno activo `(env_cvxopt) C:\users\user_name>`,  revisa si se ha instalado el paquete `cvxopt` con `conda list`.

Comment: En windows no puedes utilizar `export PATH`  necesitas modificar las variables de entorno del sistema con [setx /?](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx)  otra forma de hacerlo con un atajo para es teclear `windows + r` y ejecutar `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` (también funciona desde la consola `cmd` ) con eso puedes editar las variables de entorno.